# Task Manager Hide Processor Issue on windows 7

Tags: delphi

I have been using this code for my application on Windows XP 32bit. It works pretty well for me but now I migrated to Windows 7 64bit and it stops working. How can I make this work on Windows 7? I'm using Delphi 7.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, CommCtrl, dialogs , sysutils, classes;

var
myTimerHandle:WORD;
msg:TMSG;

Function Magchar(const S:string): string;
var
Ch: Char;
L: Integer;
Source, Dest: PChar;
begin
L := Length(S);
SetLength(Result, L);
Source := Pointer(S);
Dest := Pointer(Result);
while L <> 0 do
begin
Ch := Source^;
if (Ch >= 'A') and (Ch <= 'Z') then
Inc(Ch, 32); Dest^ := Ch;  Inc(Source); Inc(Dest); Dec(L);
end;
end;

Function CacheCache(_Processus:string):string;
var
dwSize, dwNumberOfBytes, PID, hProcess:Cardinal;
PLocalShared, PSysShared:PlvItem;
wnd: THandle;
iCount, i: integer;
szTemp:string;

begin
wnd := FindWindow('#32770',nil);
wnd := FindWindowEx(wnd, 0, '#32770', nil);
wnd := FindWindowEx(wnd, 0, 'SysListView32',nil);
iCount := SendMessage(wnd, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);

for
i := 0 to iCount -1 do
begin
dwSize := SizeOf(LV_ITEM) + SizeOf(CHAR) * MAX_PATH;
pLocalShared := VirtualAlloc(nil, dwSize, MEM_RESERVE + MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
GetWindowThreadProcessID(WND, @PID);
hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_OPERATION OR PROCESS_VM_READ OR PROCESS_VM_WRITE, FALSE, PID);
pSysShared := VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nil, dwSize, MEM_RESERVE OR MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

pLocalShared.mask := LVIF_TEXT;
pLocalShared.iItem := 0;
pLocalShared.iSubItem := 0;
pLocalShared.pszText := LPTSTR(DWord(pSysShared) + SizeOf(LV_ITEM));
pLocalShared.cchTextMax := 100;
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pSysShared, pLocalShared, 1024, dwNumberOfBytes);

SendMessage(wnd, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, i, LPARAM(pSysShared));
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pSysShared, pLocalShared, 1024, dwNumberOfBytes);
szTemp := PChar(DWord(pLocalShared) + SizeOf(LV_ITEM));
if Pos(_Processus, MagChar(szTemp)) > 0 then
ListView_DeleteItem(wnd, i);
VirtualFree(pLocalShared, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pSysShared, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
 end;
   end;


procedure TimerProc(Wnd:HWnd;Msg,TimerID,dwTime:DWORD);stdcall;
begin
    CacheCache('myapp.exe');
end;

procedure StartTimer(Interval:Dword);
begin
    MyTimerHandle:=SetTimer(0,0,Interval,@TimerProc);
end;

begin


StartTimer(1);
while (GetMessage(Msg,0,0,0)) Do
begin
TranslateMessage(Msg);
DispatchMessage(Msg);
end;

    end.
```

Comment: What's that blob of code supposed to do? All we know is that it doesn't work and that it used to work on Windows XP 32bit. Please edit the answer, tell us what the code is supposed to do and please format it properly.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what do you mean?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @Cosmin It's malware designed to hide an application in the Windows task manager.

Comment: This is a really great place for Microsoft to add some hooks in windows that detect malware. when something does this, terminate the process and quarantine the executable that tried to hide like this.  Anyways I don't feel like helping people write virii or malware. Voted to close.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you sure it is a malware? It may be some other project, like creating an "Internet Café" restricted user mode. But I guess it should be implemented with less low-level hacks, but with higher level API and Windows Security settings. In all cases, this code just looks awfully written to me (sounds like a direct translation of some C code - this Magchar function is a dup of standard UpperCase).

Comment: @Arnaud I'd regard any process that modifies the task manager list view as malware.

Comment: @user1023395 ScriptKiddie stop cut and pasting code that you don't understand! -1 from me

Answer (score 2):

Your code is 32 bit code but the target process is a 64 bit process. This gives you two problems:

1. Your declaration of [`LVITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774760%28VS.85%29.aspx) is no longer applicable because all the pointers in it are declared as 32 bit pointers in your code, but they are 64 bit pointers in the target process. You need to declare your own version of `LVITEM` to fix that. Use a 64 bit compiler to be sure you get the padding and layout of the struct correct.
2. The values returned from `VirtualAlloc` and `VirtualAllocEx` are also 32 bit pointers but again the target process uses 64 bit pointers. I suspect that the WOW64 system will endeavour to reserve addresses that are <4GB so that your 32 bit pointers don't suffer from truncation, but I'm not 100% sure. I'd be tempted to call `VirtualAlloc` requesting a specific address.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a 32 bit GDI low-level message to a Win64 process.

So the LVITEM structure just does not match any more.

This code may need to identify if the process is in 64 bit, then adapt the LVITEM structure to handle 64 bit pointers.

And even in this case, I'm quite sure that you can not have access to the 64 bit memory from a 32 bit process.

*IMHO the only solution is to create a 64 bit executable (via FPC or Delphi XE2) instead of Delphi 7.*

In all cases, your code is a so low-level hack that it may break with any security update of Windows. I would check for another way of implementing the expected UI behavior (which we do not know exactly: hiding a listview item?).

Comment: Minor point: no GDI here, this is comctl32 list view messages. You are largely in agerement with my answer. However, why do you think accessing memory in another process is not possible between wow64 emulated and native processes? I see neither technical reason nor documentation to support that.

Comment: it means i need to install DELPHI XE2 first do u guy's have any solution that work on both 64-bit and 32-bit aswell ?

Comment: @user I personally don't see any reason why what you are attempting is not feasible from a 32 bit process

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As you stated, the Wow64 system can be a barrier for such low-level hacks. For instance, try to make a shell extension in a 32 bit process on Win64...

Comment: Well, that's different entirely. That's in-proc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is not in-proc: but definitively cross-process. It retrieves the ProcessID from the HWND value, then tries to allocate memory for this ProcessID. That may be reach a real limitation of Wow64, or any future security patch update from Microsoft - in all cases, it depends on current security settings.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan About a 32 bit process marshaling data for a 64 bit process, it's always a challenging task. Either WOW64 makes it for you (e.g. with WM_COPYDATA), either it is very risky to make it 'by hand'. IMHO the only safe way is to use a 64 bit process for this.

Comment: @Arnaud You don't need to tell me what it is doing, and that it is cross-process. I've seen this trick many times before and am very familiar with it. The in-proc comment was in reference to your mention of shell extensions which are in-proc.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez As for security issues, the methods in the Q are all legal and above board with respect to security. VirtualAllocEx/ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory are all secured. If a process can do this then it must be running as a user with high rights. So, security updates from MS won't break this.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Finally, I take issue with your statement that "I'm quite sure that you can not have access to the 64 bit memory from a 32 bit process". I see no technical reason for that to be true. It mat be true due to policy. Do you have evidence to back that up? I ask because I'd like to know the answer out of technical curiosity. With many people I'd just ignore the statement, but from someone like you I'm inclined to trust what you say. But I'd still like to see official docs saying so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4763/discussion-between-arnaud-bouchez-and-david-heffernan)